# What kind of on-line / real-time applications have you deployed using R?

Tags: r, deployment, production-environment, design-decisions

R can be very useful for prototyping and some exploratory work. However, I'd like to know what kind of `on-line` or `real-time` applications have you (the SO reader) successfully deployed **using R** and why did you choose R for that task.

Questions:

- What kind of problem did it solve? *(trending, analysis, etc.)*
- Why did you choose R over other programming languages? *(pros/cons: speed, scaling, etc.)*

I'm looking for first-hand experiences, so please do not answer unless you have that.

Comment: "Real world project" and "production environment" seem like rather loaded terms.  Maybe you should define them? Otherwise the answer to your question is a trivial yes.

Comment: This question is not well-suited to SO.

Comment: I have reformatted my question. Consider reevaluating your comment or posting an answer.

Comment: R *is* useful for more than prototyping and exploratory work.

Comment: I'd be interested in seeing the answers to the first question, not the second. "What kind of on-line applications have you deployed using R?". Could be a community wiki topic.

Comment: Is this at all useful? http://www.revolutionanalytics.com/aboutus/our-customers.php

Answer (score 2):

The breadth of applications is beyond the scope of StackOverflow.

Suppose I said that Java is a fine language for mucking around with APIs, but can anyone point to where it's used in the real world for real deployments?  The list would be rather large, with, ***I kid you not,*** at least dozens of examples.

If you wish to see examples of real world use, stop by the Bay Area R Users Group, which has had presentations @ or by people from Google, Facebook, LinkedIn, Twitter, and more.  There are smaller offshoots in NYC, LA, Chicago, London, and elsewhere (there are even Aussies and Kiwis who use R).

So, the best solution to see documented usage is to go to Meetup.com, search for [city] R user group, and identify a Meetup, then select "Past" to see past presentations.

Comment: would Ross Ihaka and Robert Gentleman be amused by "there are **even** Aussies and Kiwis who use R" (emphasis added)?

Comment: I hope even Hadley would be amused.  :)  Congrats on finding the parochial entendre.  ;-)

Comment: By the way, it was meant to be winkingly illustrative, not injurious.